# When transforming or moving object, all or many other objects are affected

Tags: objects

How do I separate objects in blender 3.0 so that when I move or transform one object others are not affected?  Why is this happening?

Comment: Sounds as if you have Proportional editing enabled (white dot icon on the top toolbar). Press 'O' and see if it stops.

Comment: they could be parented to each other. try selecting everything and pressing Alt + P and selecting "Clear Parent". could you provide the .blend file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.